# Which language would you suggest to build web application? What is the fastest language to pick up and master?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web

As a complete noob, which language would you suggest to build web application? I only know a little of ASP.NET( build a small website connecting to database). What is the fastest language to pick up and master?

Comment: If you already know a little ASP.NET why not stick with that? It's pretty easy to learn. Just make sure it's MVC, not webforms, that you are learning.

Comment: @SteveDowling Now I'm really scared. I have only learned web pages. I have no idea what is MVC. All I know is that I need to create a web application that allows users to view, update and search database.  Would it make a huge difference if I used web pages instead of MVC and web forms?

Comment: MVC is a much nicer, newer, technology than webforms and it will be much better for you in the long run. Search for 'Getting started with ASP.NET MVC' and you'll find loads of examples. If you're using a newish version of Visual Studio it should be the standard template anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Language should be C#,if you want to bulid a small website try to search some example open source projects in github,It may help you to learn how to build a Asp.net website in a quick way